# Don't insert into mongo if None - scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'm using below method to insert data into mongodb using Scala driver.

```
def updateUserTestProgress(userId: Long, providerId: String, provider: String, contentId: Long, 
                           contentType: String, chapterId: Long, subjectId: Long, courseId: Long, status: String,
                           startedAt: Long, endedAt: Option[Long], endedMethod: Option[String], marksOption: Option[Double]) = {
    
    val collection = database.getCollection("user_content_progress")
    val res = collection.updateOne(
      Filters.and(
        Filters.eq("user_id", userId),
        Filters.eq("content_id", contentId)),
      Updates.combine(
        Updates.setOnInsert("course_id", courseId),
        Updates.setOnInsert("subject_id", subjectId),
        Updates.setOnInsert("chapter_id", chapterId),
        Updates.setOnInsert("content_type", contentType),

        Updates.set("status", status),
        Updates.set("last_activity_date", System.currentTimeMillis()),
        Updates.set("test_content.provider", provider),
        Updates.set("test_content.provider_id", providerId),
        Updates.set("test_content.start_time_in_millis", startedAt),
        Updates.set("test_content.end_time_in_millis", endedAt),
        Updates.set("test_content.ended_method", endedMethod),
        Updates.set("test_content.marks", marksOption)),
      new UpdateOptions().upsert(true))
    res.foreach(u => u)
  }
```

Currently I'm persisting null values if **endedAt, endedMethod, marksOption** are **None**

Instead of persisting null values if **endedAt, endedMethod, marksOption** are **None** I don't want to persist them at all into the collection.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Updates.combine` is variadic (it takes arbitrarily many `Bson`s):

```
def combine(updates: Bson*): Bson
```

This means that you can leverage the `Seq` to variadic arguments trick:

```
seq: _*
```

So:

```
val collection = database.getCollection("user_content_progress")
val updates = Seq(
  Updates.setOnInsert("course_id", courseId),
  Updates.setOnInsert("subject_id", subjectId),
  Updates.setOnInsert("chapter_id", chapterId),
  Updates.setOnInsert("content_type", contentType),
  Updates.set("status", status),
  Updates.set("last_activity_date", System.currentTimeMillis),
  Updates.set("test_content.provider", provider),
  Updates.set("test_content.provider_id", providerId),
  Updates.set("test_content.start_time_in_millis", startedAt)
) ++ Seq(
  endedAt.map(Updates.set("test_content.end_time_in_millis", _)),
  endedMethod.map(Updates.set("test_content.ended_method", _)),
  marksOption.map(Updates.set("test_content.marks", _))
).flatten

val res = collection.updateOne(
  Filters.and(
    Filters.eq("user_id", userId),
    Filters.eq("content_id", contentId)),
  Updates.combine(
    updates: _*),
  new UpdateOptions().upsert(true))
```

It's possible to get even more succinct for defining `updates`, but hopefully this gets the idea across.

Comment: When endedAt, endedMethod, and marksOption are given it is properly inserting but if not given, it is throwing exception
```exception: null```

Comment: Are you passing `None` or `null` when you have "not given"?

Comment: What is throwing the exception?

Comment: Apparently we were passing ```null``` instead of ```None``` and that was the issue. Now it is resolved when passed None. Thank you for your help @LeviRamsey